how to use ObservableProperty from the CommunityToolkit.MVVM?
I am working on WPF .Net framework 4.8.1 using CommunityToolkit 8.2.2. I've already set the LangVersion to 8.0.
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.10.5
The build keeps building failed with the error The name '' does not exist in the current context.
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Details
Warning The MVVM Toolkit source generators might not be loaded correctly, as the current project is using the packages.config setup to restore NuGet packages. Source generators require PackageReference to be used (either in a legacy-style or SDK-style .csproj project, both are supported as long as PackageReference is used).
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
public partial class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
[ObservableProperty]
private string _myTestName;
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
MyTestName = "test";
}
}

csproj file:

<PropertyGroup>
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
...
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>

<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
<Deterministic>true</Deterministic>

</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm">
<Version>8.2.2</Version>
</PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>


When i migrated the package.config to PackageReference ,the warning disapper. But still can't run.
It should run successfully. Same content and steps, no need to migrate package.config to PackageReference in .net8, it will work.
Is there anything that needs to be set up?

Could you share the sample? When I set the csproj file and rebuild it shows more errors.

Does CommunityToolkit.Mvvm support .netframework?  I see the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/

Not sure if this still works. Can't you  migrate your application to .NET 6 or 8?

According to the documentation, it does not support .NET Framework.

@Clemens. What similar nuget packages support .net framework 4.8?
